# Facing problems with rabbbitmq server

Tags: rabbitmq

My rabbitmq server is working fine but when I am trying to enable management plugin from command prompt by using

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

then I am getting a error.

> Error: {cannot_write_enabled_plugins_file}
>
> "C:\Users\vikas.mandeliya\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ\enabled_plugins"

So can anyone tell me what's going wrong ????

Thanks

Comment: The named file is either not writable by your user, or locked.  In windows (unlike Unix, which is probably where most of the tutorials come from), if the rabbitmq service is running, you may not be able to write to the config file as windows enforces an exclusive lock.  Try shutting down the rabbit server and trying again.

Comment: i have done that as you are saying ..

still i am facing problem ...

Comment: RabbitMQ folder is not getting created inside Roaming folder

C:\Users\vikas.mandeliya\AppData\Roaming

@PaulProgrammer

Answer (score 0):

I'll reply in case someone else stumbles upon it. You need to call

set RABBITMQ_BASE=C:\RabbitMQ\data

before calling the enable_plugin, point it to your config file dir. RabbitMQ on windows likes to lose its env vars.
Or set those in Computer settings and restart your cmd terminal